# Using NDSolve for differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerical-value

I'm trying to numerically solve the following differential equations **eqs** for plotting the bifurcation diagram. However, under special values of the parameter **u**, I get a problem when calculating the differential equations with NDSolve. The corresponding codes are shown as follows

Initial definitions

```
\[Alpha] = 0.005;\[Beta] = 0.2;\[Gamma] = 10;kt = 100;\[Xi]b = 0.82;
\[Beta]L = {1.8751040687119611791`8., 4.6940911330190088767`8.,7.8547574382376149826`8., 10.9955407348773432322`8.,14.1371683910464717872`8., 17.2787595320882612395`8.,20.4203522521036040901`8.};
Subscript[\[Phi], m_][x] :=Cos[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] - Cosh[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] + ((Sin[\[Beta]L[[m]]] - Sinh[\[Beta]L[[m]]])/(Cos[\[Beta]L[[m]]] + Cosh[\[Beta]L[[m]]]))*(Sin[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] - Sinh[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x]);
nig[fx_] :=N[Round[Chop[NIntegrate[fx, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 20], 10^-8], 10^-6], 6];
```

Differential equations

```
mm = 4;
eqs = Table[\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((\[Alpha]*nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], {x, 4}]]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]'\)[t])\)\) 
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], {x, 4}]]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]\)[t])\)\)
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], {x, 2}]]*\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]\)[t])\)\)
      -\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], {x, 2}]*\[Gamma]*\((1 - x)\)]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]\)[t])\)\)
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], x]]*2*\*SqrtBox[\(\[Beta]\)]*u*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]'\)[t])\)\)
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*D[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x], x]]*\[Gamma]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]\)[t])\)\)
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(mm\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(mm\)]\((\((\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(k\)]\)[x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(l\)]\)[x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*kt*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]\)[t]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(k\)]\)[t]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(l\)]\)[t])\)\)\)\)
      +\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(i\)]\)[x]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(j\)]\)[x]]*\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(j\)]''\)[t])\)\) == 0, {i, mm}];
EQs = Chop[Expand[Join[eqs]], 10^-8]
```

Initial conditions

```
{q101, q102, q201, q202, q301, q302, q401, q402} = {0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0};
ICs = {Subscript[q, 1][0] == q101, Subscript[q, 1]'[0] == q102, Subscript[q, 2][0] == q201, Subscript[q, 2]'[0] == q202, Subscript[q, 3][0] == q301, Subscript[q, 3]'[0] == q302, Subscript[q, 4][0] == q401, Subscript[q, 4]'[0] == q402};


u = 8.8;
s0 = NDSolve[Join[EQs, ICs], {Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 2], Subscript[q, 3], Subscript[q, 4]}, {t, 0, 1000}, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"]
```

---

The problem is that when the parameter value **u** is lower than 8.8, like u=8.7 or even u=6.5, the above-mentioned codes are efficient for the calculation in the interval $u\in\left(6,8.7\right)$. But when the parameter **u** beyonds 8.7, such as u=8.8, 8.9, and 9, etc, I get the following warning:

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 216267 steps reached at the point t == 83.2334874133867`

Concerning this warning, I use

- MaxSteps -> 1000000
- WorkingPrecision -> 40

But *Mathematica* still gives me the warning. When selecting MaxSteps -> Infinity, *Mathematica* will keeps running for a long time. And then, I stops it.

---

### Question

I would like to numerically solve the differential equations **eqs** with $u\in\left(6,9.5\right)$. So I am wondering:

- Is there a specific method for numerically solving the differential equations? It may be not the "ImplicitRungeKutta" or even the "NDSolve".
- I succeeded in calculating these equations when choosing **mm=2**, where mm is the number of 2-order differential equations considered. I suspect that the appearance of the warning **NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of $\times\times$ steps reached at the point t == $\times\times$** may have something to do with the value of mm, but I am not sure. Is there any other way I can do that when **mm>4**?

---

Thanks for help and insights in advance!

---

### Supplement

I have noticed MarcoB's suggestions. Some related replies could be seen in the comment section. Here, I add some changes to the subscript format of the code.

Initial definitions

```
\[Phi][m_, x_] := Cos[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] - Cosh[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] + ((Sin[\[Beta]L[[m]]] - Sinh[\[Beta]L[[m]]])/(Cos[\[Beta]L[[m]]] + Cosh[\[Beta]L[[m]]]))*(Sin[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x] - Sinh[\[Beta]L[[m]]*x]);
```

Differential equations

```
eqs = Table[\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((\
[Alpha]*nig[\[Phi][i, x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], {x, 4}]]*D[q[j, t], t])\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], {x, 4}]]*q[j, t])\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], {x, 2}]]*\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)]*q[j, t])\)\) 
- \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], {x, 2}]*\[Gamma]*\((1 - x)\)]*q[j, t])\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], x]]*2*\*SqrtBox[\(\[Beta]\)]*u*D[q[j, t], t])\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*D[\[Phi][j, x], x]]*\[Gamma]*q[j, t])\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\
(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(mm\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\
(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(mm\)]\((\((\[Phi][i, x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\[Phi]
[j, x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\[Phi][k, x] /. x -> \[Xi]b)\)*\((\[Phi][l, x] /. 
x -> \[Xi]b)\)*kt*q[j, t]*q[k, t]*q[l, t])\)\)\)\) 
+ \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(mm\)]\((nig[\[Phi][i, 
x]*\[Phi][j, x]]*D[q[j, t], {t, 2}])\)\) == 0, {i, mm}];

EQs = EQs /. {q[1, t] -> q1[t], q[2, t] -> q2[t], q[3, t] -> q3[t], q[4, t] -> q4[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, t] -> q1'[t], \!(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[2, t] -> q2'[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[3, t] -> q3'[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[4, t] -> q4'[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, t] -> q1''[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[2, t] -> q2''[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[3, t] -> q3''[t], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(q\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[4, t] -> q4''[t]}
```

Initial conditions

```
q1[0] == 0.001, q1'[0] == 0, q2[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, q3[0] == 0, q3'[0] == 0, q4[0] == 0, q4'[0] == 0
```

Comment: Did you notice that your initial conditions are defined as `ICs`, but then in your `NDSolve` call you use an undefined `ICS1`? Is that a typo? Also, your betaL values are defined with 8 digits of precision; it does not make sense to ask for a `WorkingPrecision` of 40 later on. Have you tried removing all the `WorkingPrecision`, and explicit `Method` calls? What happens if you let `NDSolve` choose the method automatically? Also, `Subscripts` are mostly a formatting convenience, but they are best avoided in calculation, where they might give rise to sneaky problems.

Comment: @MarcoB  thanks. Firstly, I would change the ICS1 to ICS later. It was right in my Mathematica codes before. Secondly, when the "WorkingPrecision->40" is neglected, the warning "the numerical integral converges too slowly" will happends. Changing the Subscripts and removing the WorkingPrecision or  the explicit method, the warning  "NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of ×××× steps reached at the point t == ××" still has. Could it be something else？

Comment: @MarcoB   I have tried to numerically solve the differential equations with mm=2 using the ode45 of Matlab. At u=8.8, 8.9, and 9, Matlab could easily solve it.  The possibility of the problem may comes from the Method. [ode45-NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27240/does-mathematica-have-a-command-analogous-to-ode45-of-matlab)